# iOS 8.3 fieldset border bug

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, ios8.3

Im trying to style fieldset border, but for some reason in iOS 8.3 it just not working as it should like the rest of browsers, I've tested the same code on android/PC/mac and all of them are working as they should, however in iOS 8.3 the border either disappears or not show up at all, here is a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy29dfbr/1/) that show the bug in Safari/chrome in iOS 8.3.

it seems to me it's bug with the way the page zooming works, if there is no meta viewport and the text is really small the border shows up but once you set up viewport and/or zoom the border disappears.

I've tested different ways to style the border using different css rules such as (border: / border-width / border-top-width), and all of them aren't working either.

does anyone have solution for this problem?

```
<style>
.border {
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000;
}
.border2 {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
</style>
<fieldset class="border1">
    <legend>border1 not working</legend>text content</fieldset>
<br></br>
<fieldset class="border2">
    <legend>border2 not working</legend>text content</fieldset>
<div class="border">border1 working</div>
<div class="border2">border2 working</div>
```

## update 1

removing the legend tag fixes the problem with the border, however that is not acceptable solution.

## update 2

iOS 9.0 fixed the bug.

Comment: For some reason the formatting for your link isn't working. It may be that you have too many spaces in front of the [1]; it's causing it to display it as code.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following CSS rules fixes the bug so far.

```
fieldset {
    padding-top:10px;
}
legend {
    float:left;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

without floating the legend tag fieldset borders wont showup.

Comment: Have a long legend text that wraps to two lines at iPhone resolution (375px).  The first line of text is missing,  only the second line is rendered.  This is fixed by adding `float:left` to the `<legend>` element.